# Oracle SQL Uniquely Update Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a  `STUDENT` table and need to update the `STUDENT_ID` values by prefixing with the letter `SS` followed by `STUDENT_ID` value. For any duplicate `STUDENT_ID` records, I should prefix the duplicate records as `SS1` `SS2`. Below is an example

Before Update:

| NUM | STUDENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9234 |
| 2 | 9234 |
| 3 | 9234 |
| 4 | 3456 |
| 5 | 3456 |
| 6 | 789 |
| 7 | 956 |

After Update:

| NUM | STUDENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SS9234 |
| 2 | SS19234 |
| 3 | SS29234 |
| 4 | SS3456 |
| 5 | SS13456 |
| 6 | SS789 |
| 7 | SS956 |

Below is the query for updating the `STUDENT_ID` for unique records.

```
update student set student_id = 'SS'||student_id ;
commit;
```

Need suggestion for updating the `STUDENT_ID` for duplicate records. There are around 1 million duplicate records in the table and total volume is around 40 million. Appreciate for any inputs for performance enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` statement correlated on the `ROWID` pseudo-column and using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID as rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY num) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET student_id = 'SS' || CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN rn - 1 END || dst.student_id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NUM, STUDENT_ID) AS
SELECT 1, CAST('9234' AS VARCHAR2(20)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '9234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '9234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '3456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '3456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '789'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, '956'  FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| NUM | STUDENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SS9234 |
| 2 | SS19234 |
| 3 | SS29234 |
| 4 | SS3456 |
| 5 | SS13456 |
| 6 | SS789 |
| 7 | SS956 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ASJtd2wN)

Comment: For some reason there's always something else to do, and I haven't learned the MERGE syntax for years now. I think I should do it.

Comment: Thank you. This had solved the update for dups

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there must be a better way, but this query can get the job done:

```
update t
set student_id = (
  select new_student_id
  from (
    select x.*, 'SS' || case when rn = 1 then '' else '' || rn end 
      || student_id as new_student_id
    from (
      select t.*, row_number() over(partition by student_id order by num) as rn
      from t
    ) x
  ) y
  where t.num = y.num
)
```

Result:

```
 NUM  STUDENT_ID 
 ---- ---------- 
 1    SS9234     
 2    SS29234    
 3    SS39234    
 4    SS3456     
 5    SS23456    
 6    SS789      
 7    SS956
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D9ItiaJV).

Comment: You can simplify your query a little bit [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kuAbJdWO) (and can probably speed it up by correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column that points directly to the row's address rather than using the `num` primary key).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do it without updating!?

I would probably try to :

```sql
    CREATE NEW_TABLE AS 
    SELECT [do the "update" here] FROM OLD_TABLE;
```

```
- add indexes on new table
- add constraints on new table
- add anything else you need on new table (foreign keys, grants...)

and then
```

```sql
DROP TABLE OLD_TABLE; 
--  and 
RENAME NEW_TABLE To OLD_TABLE;
```

SELECT with your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl as
        (
            Select 1 "NUM", 9234 "STUDENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "NUM", 9234 "STUDENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "NUM", 9234 "STUDENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "NUM", 3456 "STUDENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "NUM", 3456 "STUDENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "NUM", 789  "STUDENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 7 "NUM", 956  "STUDENT_ID" From Dual  
        )
Select
    NUM, 
    CASE WHEN Count(NUM) Over(Partition By STUDENT_ID) = 1 THEN 'SS' || STUDENT_ID 
    ELSE 'SS' || Replace(Sum(1) Over(Partition By STUDENT_ID Order By NUM) - 1, 0, '') || STUDENT_ID
  END "STUDENT_ID"
From    
    tbl
Order By NUM
```

Result:

| NUM | STUDENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SS9234 |
| 2 | SS19234 |
| 3 | SS29234 |
| 4 | SS3456 |
| 5 | SS13456 |
| 6 | SS789 |
| 7 | SS956 |

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please help with the logic for updating the duplicate records as shown in the example